# Does github actions support vnc enable?

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-services

Our company want to have test automation run by Github actions. As a part of it, we need to open vnc viewer to a client machine, Are there any possible ways to do it at the moment?

If not, are there any library or software that can create virtual display on github action

Comment: There is no built-in support or an existing marketplace task that runs vnc.

Comment: But you can call any commandline you need...